# What is a Magento "Connect Account"

Tags: magento2, marketplace

When logging into Magento's new Marketplace extension/theme store, you're presented with two options

[image]

You can log-in/signup using your standard `magento.com` account, **or** you can "Use a Connected Account".  Click on this Connect with Magento button does nothing.

What is this supposed to do?  What is a Magento Connected Account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked myself the exact same question yesterday.

I first though like you did, that it was a button but it is actually a label (see the arrow pointing to the right side).

That means you can connect to the marketplace using the same account you had on Magento Connect.

Once you enter your old Magento Connect credentials you're logged in and you gotta setup your marketplace account (it doesn't retrieve your old details unfortunately)